# Microsoft Bot Framework Client sdk

Tags: botframework, botconnector

I am looking to use Microsoft Bot Framework in my application. However, I have a custom UI chat control (designed according to my requirements) where I need to hook up this bot.(instead of having pre-configured channels like slack or skype).

Is there a client sdk for web (preferably in angular) and/or mobile available for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [DirectLine](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#navtitle).

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own client applications, web chat controls, or mobile apps that will talk to their bot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this should help

Answer (score 0):

DirectLine is always a good option to add chat functionality in your custom UI. Otherwise you can just turn on Web Chat channel and embed iframe in your webpage. This will make your job easy with very less errors.

I have seen directline causing many issues while sending requests. Web Chat is always a better option.